# Trouble Publishing WebJobs with API App on Azure

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-webjobs, azure-api-apps

Has anyone had problems deploying WebJobs with API apps on Azure from Visual Studio 2015 since Azure SDK for .NET 2.7.1? I have 4 webjobs referenced in my webjobs-list.json but the web deploy to azure just isn't publishing them any more. I'm not sure if 2.7.1 is the culprit but I did update it in the last couple of days. Is there any other files I should be looking at the diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to answer my own question here; for anyone else getting the problem I found that my Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish package had been updated to 1.0.7 but my .csproj file for the web job was still looking for 1.0.3. I reverted back to 1.0.3 using 'Manage NuGet Packages' in Visual Studio and all was well again.

Comment: This was my exact problem as well - for some reason the webjob project had 1.0.7, 1.0.9, and 1.0.12 installed on it.